# Amazon SQS call lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to trigger function thru amazon sqs trigger. The trigger is working fine but, the message is not passed into the my function.

Here is my lambda function

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class x implements RequestHandler<RequestClass, ResponseClass> {
    private LambdaLogger logger;

    public void log(String message) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        logger.log(sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + "  " + message+"\n");
    }

    public ResponseClass handleRequest(RequestClass request, Context context) {
        this.logger = context.getLogger();
        log("Request " + request);
        if (request == null || (request.getFilename() == null && request.getRecords() == null)) {
            log("No file was passed in");
            throw new RuntimeException("No file was passed in");
        }


        return new ResponseClass(null);
    }
}
```

And request class is  https://pastebin.com/Q1G6bnrA

The records are always null when I see logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken care of the execution role permissions of the Lambda?

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html):

**Execution Role Permissions**

Lambda needs the following permissions to manage messages in your Amazon SQS queue. Add them to your function's execution role.

- sqs:ReceiveMessage
- sqs:DeleteMessage
- sqs:GetQueueAttributes

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine for me:

```
package au.com.redbarn.aws.lambda2lambda_via_sqs;

import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent.SQSMessage;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
public class SQSConsumerLambda implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(SQSEvent input, Context context) {

        log.info("message received");

        List<SQSMessage> records = input.getRecords();

        for (SQSMessage record : records) {
            log.info(record.getBody());
        }

        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

Maybe try using `SQSEvent` instead of your own `RequestClass`.